# "Latest" module in opencart not working

Tags: module, opencart

The New Arrivals part in the opencart website works perfectly in localhost when I enabled the "Latest" module in admin side. But when I uploaded it to a live server it is showing the products which I had already uploaded in localhost. When I add new products it is not showing in the arrivals, it is not updating. But it is listing in the product listing page. Can anyone please help.

Answer (score 0):

You might not have added the 'Latest' to the home page.

1. Login to admin section.
2. Go to `Extensions > Modules`.
3. Install `Latest` Module, if it's not installed. Otherwise click on edit button of `Latest`.
4. Select Layout: `Home`, Position: `Content Botton`, Status: `Enabled`, Limit: `5`.

I just mentioned the way to add in home page, similarly you can add in any page.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the latest products are cached in a file `system/cache/product.latest.<LANGUAGE_ID>.<STORE_ID>.<CUSTOMER_GROUP_ID>.<LIMIT>`. If the file is not existing while the latest products are first loaded, the products are populated from DB and the cache file is created. Then every next time the products are loaded from this cache file until the cache file is deleted.

Now when You update, delete or add a product this cache file (as well as all other `product` cache files) should be deleted.

Your problem I believe lies in wrong file permissions on Your live server: **make sure to check the file permissions** for folder `system/cache` - it should be at least **775** so that the apache process has permission to delete the cache files...